# How to pick oldest file in a folder from directory

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

I had `n` number of files are there in my `../in/` directory. From those files I want the oldest file to process and send it to the `../complete/` directory. The remaining files are sent to the `../error/` directory. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

To find oldest file and move that to your desired directory, use:

```
# cd to ../in/

$ ls -lt | grep -v '^d' | tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}' | xargs -I '{}' mv '{}' ../complete/
```

Now that your oldest file has been moved out, you can move all files to `../error/`

```
$ mv -- * ../error/
```

The `--` after `mv` is necessary if you have any file/directory names starting with a `-`.

Answer (score 1):

To copy the oldest file to `../complete`:

```
cp -v "$(find ../in -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%T@ %p\0' | sort -zn | \
  sed -zn '1s/[0-9,\.]\+ //p')" ../complete
```

To copy the all except the oldest to `../error`:

```
find ../in -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%T@ %p\0' | sort -zn | \
  sed -zn '2,$s/[0-9,\.]\+ //p' | xargs -0 cp -vt ../error
```

---

**Explanation**:

- `find`

  - `-maxdepth 1` descends only 1 level; therefore it will not search the directory recusively.
  - `-type f` match only files.
  - `-printf '...'` a custom output format. `%T@` gives the file's last modification time in a timestamp, `%p` is the file's name. Notice the `\0` in the end. The files are printed null byte delimited, not newline delimited, because the newline could probably be a character in the file's name, which would then break the command.
- `sort -zn` this will read the output null byte delimited (`-z`) and sort it numerically (`-n`).
- `sed -zn` reads the output null byte delimited.

  - `1` will only match the first line (first command) and `2,$` will match all others (second command)
  - `s/[0-9,\.]\+ //p` will remove the leading timestamp from the output.
- From the second command only: `xargs -0 cp -vt ../error` processes the output null byte delimited (`-0`) and calls `cp -vt ../error` on all input, which copies the files.

---

**Example output**:

```
$ ls -lt ../in/
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 24 08:18 file2
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 24 08:18 file3
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 24 08:18 file4
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 24 08:18 file5
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jun 24 08:17 file_oldest
$ cp -v "$(...)" ../complete
'../in/file_oldest' -> '../complete/file_oldest'
$
$ find ... | xargs ... ../error
'../in/file2' -> '../error/file2'
'../in/file3' -> '../error/file3'
'../in/file4' -> '../error/file4'
'../in/file5' -> '../error/file5'
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on [Rahul’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/291774/80216#291778):

```
$ ls -ltr | grep -v '^d' | awk 'NR==2 {print $NF; exit}' | xargs -I '{}' mv -- '{}' ../complete/
```

Notes:

- You say you want to do something with “the oldest file”. 
  All the answers are assuming that you mean least recently modified. 
  If you mean least recently *changed*, say so;
  the answers will be slightly different. 
  If you mean least recently *created*,
  what you want is almost impossible in Unix.
- `ls -lt` (what Rahul used) lists the current directory
  in long format in order by modification date/time,
  with the newest first and the oldest last. 
  `ls -ltr` is the **r**everse of that; oldest first and the newest last.
- If you might have files whose names begin with a period (**`.`**),
  add the `A` option to `ls`; e.g., `ls -ltrA`. 
  (The order of the options doesn’t matter;
  you can use `ls -ltAr`, `ls -lAtr`, or even `ls -ltr -A` if you want to.)
- I lied. 
  A long `ls` listing of a directory always has a `total` line first. 
  In `ls -ltr`, the oldest entry is on the *second* line.
- `grep -v '^d'` filters out the directories (if any).
- `awk 'NR==2 { print $NF; exit }'`
  prints the last field (the filename*)
  from the second line (the oldest file) and then exits.

  - This is one fewer process than `tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}'`.
  - This might work faster, because,
    when the `awk` exits, the `ls` might also exit,
    and you would avoid generating the listing for the entire directory.
  - You can eliminate the `grep` by doing

    ```
    ls -ltr | awk '! /^d/ { count++ } count==2 { print $NF; exit }'
    ```

    but I wouldn’t advise it. 
    Overly complex scripts are hard to maintain.
- The `--` after `mv` *in the `xargs` command* is necessary
  if you have any file names starting with a **`-`**.
- You don’t really need the `xargs`. 
  You can simplify the above command to

  ```
  $ mv -- $(ls -ltr | grep -v '^d' | awk 'NR==2 { print $NF; exit }') ../complete/
  ```

________
* Like Rahul’s answer, this will fail if the filename contains space(s) or tab(s) — and even worse if it contains newline(s).

If you might have files whose names begin with a period (**`.`**),
do `shopt -s dotglob` before doing the

```
$ mv -- * ../error/
```